# After adding a new directory into controllers, fatal error thrown

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and after I added a new directory to the controllers viz, `Admin`, I updated the namespace also updated routes but somehow, I am getting a fatal error exception. Please help me figure out the problem

`App->Http->Controllers->Admin`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "admin controller";
    }

}
```

`routes.php`

```
Route::get('/admin', 'Admin\AdminController@index');
```

`snapshot of directory structure`

[image: directory]

Comment: Please post the exception message you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "admin controller";
    }

}
```

Note the "use" statement. I suspect that Laravel is looking for the Controller class, which this controller extends, but is unable to find it because of that missing statement.

Comment: @lhilton Thanks a lot. You are my hero.